# QtQuickScene Graph: Delete child node

Tags: qt, qtquick2

I develop a component to plot x vs y data curves which should be displayed in a qtquick application. For this, I created a `Plot` class derived from `QQuickItem`:

```
#include <vector>
#include "plotcurve.h"

class Plot : public QQuickItem
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:

  Plot();
  void add_curve(std::vector<double>* xdata, std::vector<double>* ydata) {
       _curves.append(new PlotCurve(xdata,ydata,this));
  }

private:
  QVector<PlotCurve *> _curves;

protected:

};
```

It has an add_curve function which adds a `PlotCurve` object as a child to the `Plot` object.

```
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QSGGeometry>
#include <QSGGeometryNode>

class PlotCurve : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PlotCurve(std::vector<double>* xdata, std::vector<double>*, QQuickItem *parent = 0): QQuickItem(parent) {...};

private:
    QSGGeometry * _geometry;
    QSGGeometryNode * _curve;

protected:
    QSGNode * updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData *data) override;
};
```

The `PlotCurve` uses the `updatePaintNode` function similar to this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-customgeometry-example.html to draw the lines.

What I am wondering now: How can I reset the plot object to its original state (removing the curves which have been added via add_curve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  for(auto &curve : _curves) {
    curve->setParent(nullptr);
    curve->setParentItem(nullptr);
    curve->deleteLater();
  }
```

does the trick